# Java - Set capable of referencing instances of a different class

Tags: java, class, set, instances

Can anyone help me with this java code?
I have two classes and need to create a **set** that can store instances of the other class. here is the sample I managed to "commit" :) 

**Class A**

```
public Class Rabbit { 

    private String age; 

    //constructor for instance of Rabbit <br>
    public Rabbit(String rabAge) {
        super();
        this.age = rabAge;
    }
```

**now class B:**

```
public class ManyRabbits {
private Set <String>  setOfRabbits;
```

now this method should create a new instance of the Rabbit and add it to the set represented by variable setOfRabbits

```
public void addRabbit (String age)` {

    //and I don't know what should go next...something like: `
    Rabbit r1 = new Rabbit("10");` <br>
    setOfRabbits.add(r1); 

}
```

Comment: It should be Set<Rabbit> instead of Set<String>

Comment: And you'll also need to override `equals` and `hashCode` in `Rabbit` (unless you want the deduplication to be done by identity).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your set declatation :

```
private Set<Rabbit> setOfRabbits;
```

And you also need to ovweride those two method in order to never insert twice the same object in the set.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // Your own implementation 
    return ...;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // Your own implementation 
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: It is misleading to suggest these implementations of `hashCode` and `equals`, since this class would behave the same as if you'd not overridden these methods. Please suggest *useful* implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Say:

```
Set<Rabbit> setOfRabbits = new HashSet<>();

setOfRabbits.add(new Rabbit());
```

When the Set will be keeping track of an unknown quantity of an object, I typically try to instantiate with an unnamed instance. This would work great for adding to a listener so that you could, say, add a new Rabbit every time the user clicks.

In this way, you could add however many Rabbit object you want. Try:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setOfRabbits.add(new Rabbit());
}
```

You may see this in older versions of Java:

```
Set<Rabbit> setOfRabbits = new HashSet<Rabbit>();
```

but it is no longer necessary

Comment: But OP wants a `Set`, not a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

your `ManyRabbits` calss should be like this

```
public class ManyRabbits
{
    private Set<Rabbit>  setOfRabbits = new HashSet<Rabbit>();

    public void addRabbit (String age) 
    { 
       Rabbit r1 = new Rabbit(age); 
       setOfRabbits.add(r1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Rabbit { 

  private String age; 

  //constructor for instance of Rabbit   
  public Rabbit(String rabAge) {
    super();
    this.age = rabAge;
  }

  // more methods if necessary
}
```

In `ManyRabbits`:

```
public class ManyRabbits {
  private Set <Rabbit> setOfRabbits = new HashSet<>();

  public void addRabbit (String age) { 
    Rabbit r1 = new Rabbit(age); 
    setOfRabbits.add(r1);
  }

  // more methods if necessary
}
```

Use it by calling something like

```
ManyRabbits manyRabbits = new ManyRabbits();
manyRabbits.addRabbit("10");
manyRabbits.addRabbit("20");
manyRabbits.addRabbit("30");
```

Comment: thanks a lot everyone. its ok when I use addRabbit and create Rabbit r1 but what if I want to create another rabbit, will it overwrite first one?I need to be able to add more rabbits to the set.